# redirect subdirectory to subdomain issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have .htaccess file like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?market/(.*)$ http://market.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?buddies/(.*)$ http://buddies.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?bazaar/(.*)$ http://bazaar.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

It works fine in market subdirectory. It redirects to the subdomain. But, There is a problem with other 2 subdirectories.

ERROR FOR OTHER 2 sub-domains:

```
The page isn't redirecting properly
```

What should I do to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because `RewriteCond` is only applicable to the very next `RewriteRule`. Your last 2 rules execute for all the hosts including `buddies` and `bazaar` and causes redirection loop.

You need these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?market/(.*)$ http://market.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?buddies/(.*)$ http://buddies.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?bazaar/(.*)$ http://bazaar.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```